# Changing linux config from 32 bit to 64 bit loses RTC

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration, clock

I have a config from a 32-bit linux 3.12.18, and was trying to compile a 64 bit version with most settings like selected drivers etc. the same as in 32 bit version. For this I used `make menuconfig` with `.config` in source tree, and checked "64 bit kernel". After installation I rebooted with this shiny new kernel, and everything worked... well almost everything. For some reason I appeared to not have `/dev/rtc*`, which was present on 32 bit kernel, and of course `hwclock` utility didn't work, while it worked on 32 bits.

I've spend some time trying to figure out what the difference is, and found that the whole `CONFIG_RTC_CLASS` thing with its children was just not mentioned in 32-bit `.config` and set as `is not set` in 64 bit version. So it looks like the kernel's default config regarding RTC is different in 32 and 64 bit compilation modes.

Why such a difference? Is PC RTC normally superseded by something else on modern 64 bit systems, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.config` for `CONFIG_RTC_DRV_CMOS=y`, `CONFIG_RTC_INTF_DEV=y` (create the /dev/rtcN device) and `CONFIG_RTC_CLASS=y` (which the other two depend on). In menuconfig, these are under `Device Drivers -> Real Time Clock`.

I do not a discrepancy in the [default x86* configs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/configs?id=v3.12), both of which set `CONFIG_RTC_CLASS`. When making a `defconfig` on `x86_64` with `v3.12` from git:

```
mario@gamma ~/dev/linux (git)-[v3.12] % mv .config .config-orig && make defconfig && grep RTC .config | grep -v '^#'
*** Default configuration is based on 'x86_64_defconfig'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
CONFIG_HPET_EMULATE_RTC=y
CONFIG_PM_TRACE_RTC=y
CONFIG_RTC_LIB=y
CONFIG_RTC_CLASS=y
CONFIG_RTC_SYSTOHC=y
CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS_DEVICE="rtc0"
CONFIG_RTC_INTF_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_RTC_INTF_PROC=y
CONFIG_RTC_INTF_DEV=y
CONFIG_RTC_DRV_CMOS=y
```

`CONFIG_X86` (`=y` for 32-bit and 64-bit) selects `CONFIG_RTC_DRV_CMOS` ([see here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/rtc/Kconfig?id=v3.12#n607)) and `CONFIG_RTC_INTF_DEV` is selected by `CONFIG_RTC_CLASS` ([see here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/rtc/Kconfig?id=v3.12#n90)).

It sounds like you did not start with a blank `.config`. When starting with a blank configuration and configuring each, can you reproduce the issue? From what I can see, simply toggling `CONFIG_X86_32=y` and `CONFIG_X86_64=y` does not change the value of `CONFIG_RTC_CLASS`.

Comment: Have you read the whole question? I've already checked these and found them to be the reason and successfully fixed this problem. The question is not how to fix, but why these options appear unchecked.